# Handshake failed: certificate verify failed (Boost ASIO)

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

Hello I'm trying to connect to a server:

```
    argv[1] = "demo.demo.com"; // or httpbin.com
    argv[2] = "39473"; // or 80
```

With this similar code:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp

The problem I am getting is this:

```
Handshake failed: certificate verify failed
```

I have tried this:

```
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);
//ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
```

Is there a way to just connect without verifying certificate.

Comment: I also tried  argv[1] = "httpbin.org"; argv[2] = "80"; but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a verification callback that returns true:

```
socket_.set_verify_callback(
    boost::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));
```

Where

```
  bool verify_certificate(bool preverified,
      boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
  {
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: Please don't recommend disabling the certificate validation without pointing out the implications. Validation is not a nuisance which need to be disabled but an essential part of TLS security.

Comment: You know. The question is just that. I agree with you. And it's not even a nuisance. It's just a thing to do (like input validation). No biggie. I don't recommend anything

Comment: Yes, you just provide example code without even telling explicitly that this code disables the validation. The problem I see is that somebody might use this code to "fix" the problem without understanding the code and its implications. There are already enough applications out there which do this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think you haven't understood this question and it's implications.

Comment: @sehe Thanks let me try this, reason I need to disable to to continue with developing with our app and will fix this verification when the whole logic is up and running. So I think this is a valid question & answer

Comment: @sehe a side question BTW, how can I make the code connect to a different port say localhost:8080

Comment: @sehe: You are correct that you answered the question and that I did not read the question fully. The problem I still have is that it is not clear for me from the question that the OP is aware of the issues of bad or none certificate validation. And this can lead to issues like described in [The Most Dangerous Code in the World:Validating SSL Certificates in Non-Browser Software](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Be that as it may, it is _much_ more appropriate as a comment to the question/OP

Comment: @xybrek Why don't you tell me ***what*** it is you actually want to achieve. We can serve you with a better answer than [when you ask about ***how***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you wanted to achieve it. Feel free to change the question here. I don't mind

Answer (score 0):

So the error indicates that the returned certificate does not match the one that was loaded.  In the example code, the loaded certificate occurs here:

```
ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");
```

As a test, you might try the following. Issue this command in a CMD shell (I'm assuming you have openssl installed):

```
openssl s_client -connect demo.demo.com:39473 -showcerts
```

Examine the returned output, and compare it to your ca.pem file. I bet they are different. You could even try replacing the content of your ca.pem file with the returned text from opensll, and hopefully that works.

Your mileage may vary.